# if the probability density of $x$ is given by

Tags: statistics

If the pdf of $X$ is given by

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 1+x & \text{for } -1< x \leq 0 \\ 1-x & \text{for } 0<x<1 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}$$

and $U=X$ and $V=X^2$

then show $U$ and $V$ are dependent.

How would I show they are dependent I know if two random variable $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

Then

$$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y)$$

I know the covariance of $COV(U,V)=0-(0)(1/12/)$ So it is zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** compute
$$
P(|U| < 1/2)
\\
P(V < 1/4)
\\
P(|U| < 1/2, V < 1/4)
$$

Comment: I see I do these integral then I show that $E(UV)$ does not equal $E(U)$ $E(V)$

Comment: you show that $E(f(U)g(V)) \neq E(f(U))E(g(V))$, with $f(U) = 1_{|U| < 1/2}$ and $g(V) = 1_{V < 1/4}$.